# String validation for chemistry elements

Tags: string, validation, abap

Can you guys show me how to validate a string of chemistry element and operators?

- I have an internal table it_element contains valid chemistry elements: Cu, Fe, Mg.
- I have an internal table it_operator contains operators: +, -, *, /.
- I have a string1 = 'Cu+Fe-Mg'.
- I have a string2 = "Ce+FF-Mg'.

How do i validate string2 is incorrect because it does not have valid chemistry elements in it_element?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you edit your question to limit it to only one topic? (I see two questions: how to split at an operator contained in a table, and how to lookup a string in a table). These are basic questions, can you tell us what you have found and tried, what issues did you face? Could you also add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Thank you.

Comment: Go to study Regular Expression and you will get your answer. This is basic character string operation algorithm in Computer Science, and if you are working on ABAP, you are expected to grasp the fundamental Computer programming algorithms. Here is an example which can inspire you: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/02/03/regular-expression-in-abap/

Answer (score 2):

```
DATA(elements) = VALUE string_table( ( `Cu` ) ( `Fe` ) ( `Mg` ) ).
DATA(operators) = VALUE string_table( ( `\+` ) ( `\-` ) ( `\*` ) ( `/` ) ).

DATA(element_list) = concat_lines_of( table = elements sep = `|` ).
DATA(operator_list) = concat_lines_of( table = operators sep = `|` ).

DATA(matcher) = |^(?:(?:{ operator_list })\{0,1\}(?:{ element_list }))*$|.

DATA(match) = match( val = string regex = matcher ).

result = xsdbool( match = string ).
```

From your question, the precise format that you require is not clear. (Maybe it's clear to chemistry pros, but I am not intimately familiar with the notation.) I assume that the regular expression `^(?:(?:\+|\-|\*\/){0,1}(?:Cu|Fe|Mg))*$` fits your purpose.